# Connection to VPN server

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I just created an **OpenVPN** instance on my private server, running on debian 7.
I attempt to connect with **OpenVPN GUI**, server binded and connection established on the right port, but I've got the following error :

```
Wed Apr 08 10:22:43 2015 OpenVPN 2.0.9 Win32-MinGW [SSL] [LZO] built on Oct  1 2006
Wed Apr 08 10:22:43 2015 IMPORTANT: OpenVPN's default port number is now 1194, based on an official port number assignment by IANA.  OpenVPN 2.0-beta16 and earlier used 5000 as the default port.
Wed Apr 08 10:22:43 2015 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Wed Apr 08 10:22:43 2015 Control Channel Authentication: using 'ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
Wed Apr 08 10:22:43 2015 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Apr 08 10:22:43 2015 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Apr 08 10:22:43 2015 LZO compression initialized
Wed Apr 08 10:22:43 2015 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1560 D:168 EF:68 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Wed Apr 08 10:22:43 2015 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1560 D:1450 EF:60 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Wed Apr 08 10:22:43 2015 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '2f2c6498'
Wed Apr 08 10:22:43 2015 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '9915e4a2'
Wed Apr 08 10:22:43 2015 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [SERVER IP]:5001
Wed Apr 08 10:22:43 2015 TCP connection established with [SERVER IP]:5001
Wed Apr 08 10:22:43 2015 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Wed Apr 08 10:22:43 2015 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [SERVER IP]:5001
Wed Apr 08 10:22:43 2015 TLS: Initial packet from [SERVER IP]:5001, sid=b0821320 198b666d
Wed Apr 08 10:22:43 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=1, /C=US/ST=CA/L=SanFrancisco/O=Fort-Funston/OU=changeme/CN=changeme/name=changeme/emailAddress=mail@host.domain
Wed Apr 08 10:22:43 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=0, /C=US/ST=CA/L=SanFrancisco/O=Fort-Funston/OU=changeme/CN=changeme/name=changeme/emailAddress=mail@host.domain
Wed Apr 08 10:22:44 2015 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Wed Apr 08 10:22:44 2015 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Apr 08 10:22:44 2015 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Wed Apr 08 10:22:44 2015 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Apr 08 10:22:44 2015 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA
Wed Apr 08 10:22:44 2015 [changeme] Peer Connection Initiated with [SERVER IP]:5001
Wed Apr 08 10:22:45 2015 SENT CONTROL [changeme]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Wed Apr 08 10:22:45 2015 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 4.4.4.4,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,route 10.8.0.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.6 10.8.0.5'
Wed Apr 08 10:22:45 2015 Options error: unknown --redirect-gateway flag: bypass-dhcp
Wed Apr 08 10:22:45 2015 Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:5: topology (2.0.9)
Wed Apr 08 10:22:45 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Wed Apr 08 10:22:45 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Wed Apr 08 10:22:45 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Wed Apr 08 10:22:45 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Wed Apr 08 10:22:45 2015 CreateFile failed on TAP device: \\.\Global\{B3D53F8D-05D6-4E31-803D-4A069D8BB81A}.tap
Wed Apr 08 10:22:45 2015 All TAP-Win32 adapters on this system are currently in use.
Wed Apr 08 10:22:45 2015 Exiting
```

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: How to resolve the error, cause connection failed.

_sorry, i'm a developer first_

Comment: `Wed Apr 08 10:22:45 2015 Options error: unknown --redirect-gateway flag: bypass-dhcp
Wed Apr 08 10:22:45 2015 Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:5: topology (2.0.9)`

Comment: Ans the error prompt shows "Cannot connect to client"